# Как cоздавать различные view в adaptor

Tags: android, recyclerview.adapter

Добрый день.
Есть листинг основанный на RecyclerView. Есть необходимость для некоторых строк для холдера применять другую view. Как можно это сделать. Вот мой адаптер.

```
private class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FragmentList.Holder> {
    int temp;
    private List<Hobby> mList;

    public Adapter(List<Hobby> list) {
        mList = list;
    }

    @Override
    public FragmentList.Holder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
        View view;
              view = layoutInflater
                .inflate(R.layout.hobbylist_item, parent, false);
         return new FragmentList.Holder(view);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(FragmentList.Holder holder, int position) {
              holder.bindHolder(position, hobby);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mList.size();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Реализуйте в адаптере метод `public int getItemViewType(int position)` и возвращайте тип вью в зависимости от позиции.

Затем в методе `onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)` можете подставлять разметку в зависимости от `viewType`.